# Is it possible to express $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ in a single formula?

Tags: number-theory, functions

*Yes, this seems to be silly question, but please listen to my thought.*

> Example: $n\in\mathbb{N}$ , Let $f(n)=2n-1$ and $g(n)=2n$, Now look at this function: $$H(n)=n$$
>   If We *"combine"* $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ we get $h(n)$

Question: İf $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $$f(n)=\frac{2^{8n-3}-2^{2n-1}-3}{9}$$
$$g(n)=\frac{2^{8n-4}-2^{2n}-3}{9}$$

**Is it possible to express $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ in a single formula?**

Ps. English is not my mother language. I may not have been clear my question. For a better understanding of the problem please, edit.
Thank you!

Comment: That word "combine" is not clear. I don't see how you get $n$ combining $2n$ and $2n-1$.

Comment: Not a duplicate of this deleted question ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327237/is-it-possible-to-combine-these-functions

Comment: Set of $f(n)$ + set of $g(n)$ = $h(n)$ I have a problem with mathematics symbols.I am sorry.

Comment: @Crostul I think he's saying the union of the co-domains of $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{O}$ and $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{E}$ is $\mathbb{N}$, which is the co-domain of $H : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ ($\mathbb{O} \cup \mathbb{E} = \mathbb{N}$). This is what I believe he's implying. or maybe he's saying the union of the ranges. not sure.

Comment: @Dando yes, yes You were right! Please edit, my question with mathematical symbols.İ can not. Thank you!

Comment: @Dando18  Yes, you were right. Please help me for express my problem..

Answer (score 1):

A simple example would be:
$$H(n)=\frac12((-1)^n+1)f(n/2)+\frac12(-1^{n+1}+1)g((n+1)/2)$$
For all $m\in\Bbb{N}$, we have:
$$H(2m)=\frac12(1+1)f(m)+\frac12(-1+1)g((2m+1)/2)=f(m)$$
$$H(2m-1)=\frac12(-1+1)f((2m-1)/2)+\frac12(1+1)g(m)=g(m)$$

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you want might be "interpolate." What you're essentially doing with $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ is letting

$$H(1)=f(1),\ H(2)=g(1)$$

$$H(3)=f(2),\ H(4)=g(2)$$

$$H(5)=f(3),\ H(6)=g(3)$$

$$\vdots$$

so you're defining $H(2n-1)=f(n)=2n-1$ and $H(2n)=g(n)=2n$, so $H(x)=x$ for all integers $x$. You can do the exact same thing with your new functions and get

$$H(x)=\bigg\{\begin{array}{cc}\frac{1}{9}\left(2^{4x+1}-2^x-3\right) & \mathrm{if\ }x\ \mathrm{is\ odd} \\ \frac{1}{9}\left(2^{4x-4}-2^x-3\right) & \mathrm{otherwise}\end{array}$$

It doesn't look as nice as $H(x)=x$, but it's a function nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. that what wolfie says, when i try to put first values of that functions: $g(n)$, $f(n)$ [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1,+3,+453,+909,+116501,+233013,+29826133,+59652309,+7635497301,+15270994773,+...]

Comment: link formatting syntax $\to$ `[text](https://link.link.com)`

Comment: Yes, İt may be true answer of my question! +1.thanks.

Comment: I checked!Wolframapha says absolutely true..